# Why am I getting *ngIf not a property of div error?

Tags: angular

I am using a version of Cory Rylan's technique to display validation error messages on my forms.  This worked fine in RC4, however, I can't figure out what to do to make this work with RC5.

Here's my pared down SharedModule:

```
import { NgModule, ModuleWithProviders } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';
import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';

import { ValidationService } from '../services/validation.service';
import {ValidationMessageComponent} from '../validation/validation.message.component;

@NgModule({
  imports: [CommonModule, RouterModule, MenubarModule ],
  declarations: [ ValidationMessageComponent ],
  exports: [ CommonModule, ReactiveFormsModule, HttpModule, ValidationMessageComponent ]
})

export class SharedModule {
  //
  static forRoot(): ModuleWithProviders {
    return {
      ngModule: SharedModule,
      providers: [ ValidationService ]
    };
  }
}
```

The ValidationMessageComponent:

```
import { Component, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { FormControl } from '@angular/forms';
import { ValidationService } from '../services/validation.service';

@Component({
  moduleId: module.id,
  selector: 'kg-validationMessage',
  template: `<div *ngIf="validationMessage !== null">{{validationMessage}}</div>`
}) 


export class ValidationMessageComponent {
  @Input() control: FormControl;
  constructor() { }

  get validationMessage() {
    for (let propertyName in this.control.errors) {
      if (this.control.errors.hasOwnProperty(propertyName) && this.control.touched) {
        return ValidationService.getValidatorErrorMessage(propertyName, this.control.errors[propertyName]);
      }
    }

    return null;
  }
}
```

The error happens in the template *ngIf.  The html I'm trying to inject this into has a number of *ngIf's, all of which work fine. I've tried every combination to no avail.  Any help sincerely appreciated.

Comment: `template: 'div *ngIf=` is missing a `<` at the beginning.

Comment: Should the `ValidationMessageModule` contain the `SharedModule` in `imports: [...]`?

Comment: Sorry that's a typo on my part.  It has it in the code.

Comment: When I import the SharedModule, this is the error: "Unexpected value 'undefined' imported by the module 'function ValidationMessageModule() {

Comment: Seems to cause some circular dependency. I didn't see that `SharedModule` imports `ValidationMessageModule` Then import `CommonModule` directly instead.

Comment: Still unexpected value error...

Comment: I guess this needs a Plunker to reproduce.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want `ValidationMessageModule` to depend on (import) `SharedModule`, you cannot also make `SharedModule` depend on (import) `ValidationMessageModule`. You will end up with a circular reference as @StefanSvrkota mentioned in his comments.

Because your current `SharedModule` is exporting `ValidationMessageModule`, I deduce that you want this message module to be shared across the modules in your application.  The simplest fix to your problem is to just bring `ValidationComponent` into `SharedModule` and get rid of `ValidationMessageModule` altogether.  I would change the **SharedModule** to:

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [CommonModule, RouterModule, MenubarModule],

  //all your components, pipes & directives meant to be shared
  declarations: [ValidationComponent],

  //modules to share, but also everything from declarations array
  exports: [ CommonModule, ReactiveFormsModule, HttpModule, ValidationComponent]
})

export class SharedModule {
  //
  static forRoot(): ModuleWithProviders {
    return {
      ngModule: SharedModule,
      providers: [ ValidationService]
    };
  }
}
```

Basically, don't import into `SharedModule` other modules that depend on `SharedModule`. Instead, make their components, directives and pipes part of the shared module since you want to share them

Comment: Thank you all for your help.  I was finally able to get it working by following this answer.  Thanks again.

Comment: I also had a circular reference. I'd wish I'd get an error on that, instead of some other completely random error message (*ngIf not a know att. etc.)... But a big thanks for the help to you, sir :)

Answer (score 8):

You need to add `CommonModule` from `@angular/common` to your `ValidationMessageModule` imports because `CommonModule` provides common directives such as `ngIf` or `ngFor`. You can use `ngIf` in your root module because you have `BrowserModule` imported and `BrowserModule` re-exports `CommonModule`.

Comment: CommonModule is imported and exported in the sharedModule, I don't import it in the parent which works fine.

Comment: Then you need to add `SharedModule` to your `ValidationMessageModule` imports in metadata of `@NgModule`, it is not enough to just do `import { SharedModule } from '../shared/shared.module';`.

Comment: @JohnBaird But, if you do that, you will have circular dependency which will produce an error. If you read Angular Module FAQ's, you will see that Angular does not like modules with circular references so don't let Module 'A' import Module 'B' which imports Module 'A'. Solution for your problem would be to remove `SharedModule` import from your `ValidationMessageModule` and add `CommonModule` instead.